# Is a Deutsch splitter safe to use for CAN bus network?

Tags: can

We want to use  Deutsch splitter for a CAN bus network. But I know that CAN bus networks do not like star topology.

My question: Is a Deutsch splitter considered to be a "star"?

[image: deutsch splitter]

Comment: Where's the datasheet for the deutsch splitter you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I know that CANBUS networks do not like star topology.

For low-speed CAN (ISO 11898-3, up to 125 kBaud) it doesn't matter if it's star or bus or a mixture of them as each node has its own termination. But for high-speed CAN (ISO 11898-2, up to 1 MBaud) the topology should be bus (linear) i.e. having stub lengths of less than 1 metre and terminations at both ends of the bus only (i.e. not at the nodes).

> Does deutsch splitter consider as star?

Splitter hardware has nothing to do with the topology. It joins multiple connections into one or splits one connection into multiple ones. Regardless of the topology you can use splitters. So, what matters is your topology.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ4K56.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diagram above represents a bus (linear) topology for ISO 11898-2 High-speed CAN. Each splitter on its own is a Y (or T or star) connector, but they don't convert the entire topology into a star as long as the stub lengths are kept at less than 1 metre (or considerably shorter than the bus length), as shown.

Comment: Hey thanks, But the specific splitter implies star, isnt?

Comment: Yeah but if you have a linear bus and you split it in the middle to two, then it's not linear any more but a star. Having said that, if the stub length is sufficiently short, it is still considered linear.

Comment: @oak see the update.

Answer (score 3):

Deutsch is mainly a connector manufacturer and these things are mostly just "dumb" connectors, except they might come with an option to add 120 ohm terminators.

A CAN bus should be designed as a "multi-drop" bus with every node sitting along a long signal line, with terminating resistors at each end of that line. However, this is a bit of an utopia and not always practical. Quite often we have to resort to "stubs", signals splitting up and "leaving" the main bus. A stub does not necessarily mean star topology - the general recommendation is to keep stubs very short, some rule of thumb <300mm.

CAN is very rugged however, and will probably handle longer stubs just fine as long as there is always 60 ohm between CANH and CANL. The higher the baudrate, the pickier it gets though. If you keep baudrates < 100kbps you can get away with *a lot* of not recommended practices. When they get nearer to 1Mbps, following best practices becomes more important. The total bus length is also important - the longer the bus, the more vulnerable it gets.

A typical application for these kind of splitters is for example to get mounted next to a hydraulic valve rack on some mobile machinery, where each of multiple valves use CAN e-modules and each valve has a Deutsch connector. You would then have very short stubs, one per valve, and that will be fine.